# What are the >> and << operators in Python?

Tags: python, operators, bitwise-operators

What are `>>` and `<<` for?

I read this in code:

https://github.com/mlaiosa/emlx2maildir/blob/master/emlx2maildir.py

```
FL_READ = (1<<0)
FL_DELETED = (1<<1)
FL_ANSWERED = (1<<2)
FL_ENCRYPTED = (1<<3)
FL_FLAGGED = (1<<4)
FL_RECENT = (1<<5)
FL_DRAFT = (1<<6)
FL_INITIAL = (1<<7)
FL_FORWARDED = (1<<8)
FL_REDIRECTED = (1<<9)
FL_SIGNED = (1<<23)
FL_IS_JUNK = (1<<24)
FL_IS_NOT_JUNK = (1<<25)
FL_JUNK_LEVEL_RECORDED = (1<<29)
FL_HIGHLIGHT_IN_TOC = (1<<30)
```

I cannot find the documentation of it yet.

Comment: Same as in any other language, really.

Comment: Sorry i am not used to bit shifting. Not in high level languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's bitshift operator. If you have a 1(`0b1`), and shift it left 4 bits(`1 << 4`), what you get is 0b10000, which means 16.

And here's the documentation: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations

Comment: Thanks a lot , is that still useful in high level langauge as python? What are their PRACTICAL uses?

Comment: I'm not sure about it's performance advantages, but I know one practical use of them: setting flags(like in the code you posted). For example, you can use 16bit integer to hold 16 flags with this: first, you assign a flag `1`, then you assign second flag `1 << 1`, third flag `1 << 2` etc. And when checking this flags, and when you checking for a flag you use `flag & flag_name`, if it yields 1, you have the flag, 0, you don't.

Comment: Thanks quite confusing but i will look more into it.

Comment: V3ss0n, I think this could be a good start http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: What i read from wikipedia is bitshifting is in pritical use at system/driver programming. Not really useful for me i think.

Comment: Sometimes it's relevant when you have to deal with data that was originally prepared for use in a lower-level language, that encodes values that way.

Answer (score 2):

The operators are defined in [section 5.7, "Shifting Operations", of the Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations):

> These operators accept plain or long integers as arguments. The arguments are converted to a common type. They shift the first argument to the left or right by the number of bits given by the second argument.
>
> A right shift by *n* bits is defined as division by `pow(2, n)`. A left shift by *n* bits is defined as multiplication with `pow(2, n)`. Negative shift counts raise a `ValueError` exception.

Answer (score 1):

In most languages, including Python, those are shift-operators.  They work on the bits of a byte.

For example, 8 is `0b00001000`. `8 >> 1` means shift the bits of it 1 digit to the right, adding a zero at the left (`0b00000100` or 4). `8 >> 2` means shift it to the right twice. (`0b00000010` or 2). The `<<` is a left shift, which works in the opposite way. `8 << 1` would come out to `0b00010000` or 16. `8 << 2` would come out to `0b00100000` or 32.

See the python documentation for more information.
Python 2.x: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations
Python 3.x: http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations